# AWS API Gateway resource: invalid or unknown key: tags

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

When I run the following terraform template:

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_resource" "api_method_resource" {
rest_api_id = "${var.api_id}"
parent_id = "${var.resource_id}"
path_part = "${var.url_path}"
tags = "${merge(
local.common_tags,
map(
"Name", "${var.env}_api_method_resource"
))}"
}
```

I got the following error:

```
Error: aws_api_gateway_resource.api_method_resource: : invalid or unknown key: tags
```

What would be wrong with adding tags to AWS API Gateway Resource?

Comment: you have `"` inside of other `"` for the tags value. Do you have to escape the internal ones? `\"`

Comment: I think so, anyway it should not cause it fail, especially that I've tried it with other resources and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

You can't currently tag API Gateway resources so the `tags` parameter isn't supported in the [`aws_api_gateway_resource` resource](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/api_gateway_resource.html).

Comment: but auto_scaling_group does not has "tag" argument https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/d/autoscaling_group.html and I still can add tags to this resource.

Comment: You're looking at the data source, not the resource: https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/autoscaling_group.html